# Get customers age in months from a given column (SQL Server 2017)

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL just wanted to know if I have one row with date of birth of few customers and I have to create a new column while creating a view with the customer_id and customer age in month as of today(Age_in_months = Current date - Date of birth of customer). How do I do it ?

I have tried date diff , some suggested to use floor and cast but I keep getting errors

One of them

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '01-05-1974' to data type int.

Can somebody please suggest a very simple solution to this?

Thank you!

Comment: can't you use the SQL function `DATEDIFF` ?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `DATEDIFF`???  It's part of programmer's job to read documentation and debug errors.

Comment: Can you run: select Datediff(MM,getdate(),getdate()+1000)

Comment: `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '01-05-1974'` why store dates as strings?? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @bruceg- Sorry but I have tried using the date diff and I got Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided the Table or Column names I will assume the Table is Customers and the columns are id and dob.

Here is some example SQL to get the information

```
select 
    id as [Customer ID],
    dob as [Date Of Birth], 
    datediff(month, cast(dob AS DATE), getdate()) as [Age In Months]  
from 
    customers
```

First, we will take the Date Of Birth and make sure it is a date and not a Varchar or int, then we wrap that in a DATEDIFF to get the difference between the date in the dob column and the current date in months.

And this is the output

```
Customer ID Date Of Birth     Age In Months
----------- ----------------- ------------- 
1           01-01-1991          331 
2           01-01-2018          7
```

Comment: Hello @CloudTheWolf - I tried running this command as you mentioned above 

select customer_Id as [Cust_ID],DOB as [Date Of Birth],
 DATEDIFF(month, cast(DOB AS DATE), GETDATE()) as [Age In Months]  from customer;

I get the msg 
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Thanks you as I see your query works fine went data is inserted manually . I imported the CSV file so this created a string type entry in sql . Your query gave me the same error I just had to fix it with convert 
select customer_Id ,DOB,
 DATEDIFF(month, CONVERT(date, Customer.DOB, 103), GETDATE()) as [Age In Months]  from Customer;

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you as I see your query works fine went data is inserted manually . I imported the CSV file so this created a string type entry in sql . Your query gave me the same error I just had to fix it with convert

```
select customer_Id ,
DOB, DATEDIFF(month, CONVERT(date, Customer.DOB, 103), GETDATE()) as 
[Age In Months] from Customer;
```